# Parse Object Not Updating Without Parse Query

Tags: parse-platform

I have one Parse object in my user table and I added some data to it in one column.  When I reference this data straight away it shows as undefined but when I retrieve the object through a query it shows the data.  What is going on here?

```
console.log(Parse.User.current().get("contractorCode"))//this is undefined

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.get(Parse.User.current().id, {
     success: function(test){
     console.log("test", test.get("contractorCode"));//this returns the data
     }
   })
```

What is going on here and how do I get the data recognized in Parse without the extra query?  It seems as if it needs to be in there a certain amount of time to refresh (which I actually pushed on both the browser and on the Parse dashboard set up).  Is this so or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this happens you must log out of your app and back in.  It has something to do with the new sessions feature by Parse.